# can't find task retention settings in oracle apex 22.2.5

Tags: oracle-apex

as per
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmdb/about-the-retention-and-archival-of-tasks.html#GUID-0F8B7CC6-36AD-4D55-9540-115C5CC90AF9

> Task Retention Settings
>
> Task Retention Settings are visible under Workspace Preferences, Approval Settings. The default setting is 7 days, and the maximum setting is 30 days.

the approval setting should be under workspace prefrences

i can't find it

running apex 22.2.5

Comment: I don't have access to any Apex version higher than 20.2 as **admin**; on apex.oracle.com, connected as **developer**, there's no such setting available under "Workspace preferences". However, if you can access Apex admin application, maybe you'll find it there.

Comment: i can access admin and it's not there either

Answer (score 0):

found it @ https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeadm/configuring-workflow-settings.html#GUID-27C214B0-5278-4464-B9B8-FFC46A45BEAB

> To specify the number of days human tasks are retained:
>
> Sign in to APEX Administration Services.
> Click Manage Instance. Under  Instance Settings, click Instance Settings. Find Workflow Settings.
> In Retention Period Days, enter the number of days completed human tasks
> are retained in the instance before being purged. Default value is 7
> days, but cannot be greater than 30 days. Click Apply Changes.